# Arduino Tower Pro SG90 Continuous rotation servo Control

Tags: arduino, servo

I have Hacked Tower SG90 for continuous rotation. I can control it for forward and backward motion. But I don't know how to stop the servo. I am using arduino nano to control Servo. Here is my code :

```
#include <Servo.h> 
Servo myservo;  // create servo object to control a servo 

void setup() {
  myservo.attach(14);
}

void loop() {
  myservo.write(0); // for forward motion
  delay(1000);
  myservo.write(180); // for backward motion
  delay(1000);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
myservo.write(90)
```

From [Arduino Documentation](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/ServoWrite)

> Writes a value to the servo, controlling the shaft accordingly. On a
>   standard servo, this will set the angle of the shaft (in degrees),
>   moving the shaft to that orientation. On a continuous rotation servo,
>   this will set the speed of the servo (with 0 being full-speed in one
>   direction, 180 being full speed in the other, and a value near 90
>   being no movement).

Comment: What do you observe when you set it to 90?

Comment: It was moving forward on 90 didnt stop.

Comment: It may be a value close to 90 that will make it stop.

Comment: @ChathurangaChandrasekara did you ever figure this out? I have a similar issue with a continuous servo hack.

Comment: @Ben No. I haven't tested this. Did you try a value close to 90 rather than 90?

Comment: @TheSuperKat Do you have any update with you on this?

Comment: @TheSuperKat It's great if you can share your solution. There are few who are interested on it :)

Comment: @Chathuranga Chandrasekara

Yeah Sure,, I just But I just got the servo working by experimenting on values one by one,,, I just got the hint that it was near around 90 so I tested all the values near 90 and It worked.

Comment: @TheSuperKat Thanks :-)

Comment: @Ben : I think The Super Kat has answered your query

Comment: @Chathuranga Chandrasekara Your Welcome